# New to HTML5 and JavaScript, and I can't connect JavaScript file to HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am having a problem with HTML5 and javascript.
I made a few .js files for the javascript part and I made the link to connect it with the HMTL code but it will not show the javascript part.
This is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Gateway Tunes</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="playlist_store.js"></script>
<script src="playlist.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<form> 
    <input type="text" id="songTextInput" size="40" placeholder="Song name">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Song">
</form>
<ul id="playlist">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and here are my javascript files; the names of the files are at the top

playlist_store.js

```
function save(item) {
    var playlistArray = getStoreArray("playlist"); 
    playlistArray.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem("playlist", JSON.stringify (playlistArray));
    }
function loadPlaylist() {
    var playlistArray = getSavedSongs();
    var ul = document.getElementById('playlist");
    if (playlistArray !Null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < playlistArray.length; i++) {
        li.innerHTML = playlistArrray[i];
        ul.appenChild(li);
        }
    }
}

function getSavedSongs() {
    return getStoreArray("playlist")
}
function getStoreArray (key);
    var playlistArray = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if(playlistArray == null || playlistArray == "") {
        playlistArray = new Array();
    }
    else {
        playlistArray = JSON.parse (playlistArray);
    }
    return playlistArray;
}
```

playlist.js

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById ("addButton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
    loadPlaylist();
}
function handleButtonClick () {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");

var songName = textInput.value;

if (songName == "") {
    alert("Button was clicked!");
    }
    else {

 alert("Your track has been added!");

 }
    var li = document.createElement("li");

    li.innerHTML = songName;

    var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");

    ul.appendChild(li);
    save (songName);
  }
```

Comment: @Pshemo Came here for this comment.

Comment: `var ul = document.getElementById('playlist");` has an error, change it to both single quotes or double quotes.

Comment: Whatever you wrote these on, an editor with proper syntax highlighting is a must if you intend to write code. StackOverflow's basic syntax highlighting alone should pretty much tell you where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some syntax errors so your javascript isn't running.

In playlist_store.js

```
var ul = document.getElementById('playlist");
```

Opens a string with `'` but tries to close it with `"`. It doesn't matter which you use as long as you're consistent, so you can either change it to `'playlist'` or `"playlist"`.

```
if (playlistArray !Null) {
```

If you're trying to make sure `playlistArray` isn't null you can do

```
if (playlistArray != null) {
```

notice `!=` as the comparison and `null` needs to be lowercase. If you want to make sure it isn't just undefined or null you can simply do `if (!playlistArray)`.

`ul.appenChild(li);` needs to be `ul.appendChild(li);`.

I'm sure there's more, check over your code.

Answer (score -1):

The first line of your script (and the only one that isn't just a function definition) is `window.onload = init;`.  This means that after the page has loaded, your `init` function is called.

This function looks up the element with id `addbutton`, and then calls a method on the returned result.  Since you don't *have* an element with this ID, there won't be any object returned, and so an exception will be thrown (something like "button is null or not an object", depending on your browser).  This exception stops the method from executing further - and in particular, `loadPlaylist()` will not be called.

---

The moral of the story here though is **pay attention to the JavaScript error console**, especially while you're doing development!  You browser will almost certainly have displayed a red exclamation mark icon or similar, which you could double-click to give you the name, message and location of the exception.

You really don't need to post your code listing on Stack Overflow to ask *us* what's wrong with it, when your browser is already capable of telling you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: There is indeed an element with the ID `addButton`. `<input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Song">`